# Ubuntu 14.04 KVM - error: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: qemu-system-x86_64:

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, migration

I am trying to migrate a KVM guest from one Ubuntu 14.04 host to another by following the steps [outlined here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/linuxonibm/liabp/liabpofflinemigration.htm).

I now have the "state" file, xml configuration, and qcow2 img file in a single folder on the new host, and made sure to update the xml configuration to point to the new location of the qcow2 image file.

When I try to run `virsh create [guest-id].xml` I get the following error message:

```
error: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: 
qemu-system-x86_64: -drive file=/media/stuart/storage2/kvm/dns.technostu.com/dns.technostu.com.img,if=none,id=drive-virtio-disk0,format=raw: 
could not open disk image /media/stuart/storage2/kvm/dns.technostu.com/dns.technostu.com.img: 
Could not open '/media/stuart/storage2/kvm/dns.technostu.com/dns.technostu.com.img': Permission denied
```

#### Debugging and Attempted workarounds

- I have already added myself to the libvirtd group and re-logged in.
- I made sure the filepaths were correct
- I changed the ownership of the .img file to myself, but after running the command with and without sudo, the ownership of the file keeps changing to `root:root` with permissions `-rwxr-xr-x`
- I tried running

  ```
  sudo apt-get install apparmor-profiles apparmor-utils
  sudo aa-complain /usr/lib/libvirt/virt-aa-helper
  ```

  From [this post](https://github.com/adrahon/vagrant-kvm/issues/163), but that hasn't worked.
- I tried changing the emulator in the xml file as specified [here](https://superuser.com/questions/606923/error-while-creating-a-vm-using-kvm).

What do I need to do in order to "import" the guest on the new host on Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turning the computer off and on again (I hadn't rebooted since installing `kvm`) changed the error message to:

```
error: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: qemu-system-x86_64
```

When Googling that error, I found [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/298426/kvm-image-failed-to-start-with-virsh-permission-denied?answertab=active#tab-top) which recommended adding the following to

```
user = "root"
group = "root"
```

to the `/etc/libvirt/qemu.conf` file. Be sure to include the quotes.

After another reboot, I was able to run `virsh create [guest-id].xml` successfully.

Comment: Similar problem solved after adding these lines. Then run `sudo virt-manager` without any reboot its work.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem.

Adding my user to the kvm group

```
sudo usermod -a -G kvm username
```

Then I made sure that `/dev/kvm` is owned by root and group kvm

Afterwards I changed the ownership of my existing VM (converted from VirtualBox) 
to username:kvm

Finally I set `group=kvm user=username` in my qemu.conf
This fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

Running QEMU with root privileges is not advised, as from version 6.0.0 it would not strip the Linux capabilities.

In my case it was AppArmor. I wanted to add an SSDT file for a battery to the VM. There are some folders which AppArmor allows access to, and others (like `/home/something`) are just not allowed. `/var/lib/libvirt/images/` is one of the allowed folders. Although i placed my file there, it was still not allowed by AppArmor policy (as can be seen with `sudo cat /var/log/kern.log | grep -C 10 apparmor | grep -C 10 qemu`). What worked was adding `/var/lib/libvirt/images/SSDT1.dat rk` in `/etc/apparmor.d/libvirt/TEMPLATE.qemu` like this:

```
#
# This profile is for the domain whose UUID matches this file.
#

#include <tunables/global>

profile LIBVIRT_TEMPLATE flags=(attach_disconnected) {
  #include <abstractions/libvirt-qemu>
  /var/lib/libvirt/images/SSDT1.dat rk,
}
```